# Click url (With a parameter on it), New Page Loads and Javascript sets Iframe src on Page load

Tags: javascript, iframe

**Page A :** Any page.

**Page B :** Page that has Iframe on it

What I would to do is something like this.

There is a link on Page A to Page B, Something like: **"abcd.com/thewall?parameter"**

When they click the url to **"abcd.com/thewall"** the site loads like it always does with a set `src` for the `iframe`. But when they click the `url` with the parameter like **"abcd.com/thewall?parameter"** the Iframe will automatically load a **different src** into that iframe.

I've found many references to do stuff LIKE this on here but none of them do exactly what is described above.

Also I don't know if its possible but would it be able to also when that new url is loaded into the `src` of the iframe via the parameter call have it auto scroll to the iframe?

I basically know 0 about JavaScript, so please keep it simple so i can understand.

Thank you.

Comment: What is this parameter exactly? What JavaScript library you use on this page?

Comment: The parameter i would like to use is "virool"
Library... No Clue lol What ever works best i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the query string [like this](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-QueryString-ParseGet-QueryString-with-Client-Side-JavaScript.aspx) and set the iframe's src `onDOMReady`. Since jQuery is what I'm most familiar with, that's what I'll use:

```
function getQuerystring(key, default_) {
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)"), qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (default_==null) default_=""; 
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    if(qs == null) return default_;
    return qs[1];
}
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('iframe').attr('src', getQuerystring('iframesrc', 'virool')); 
});
```

This uses a modified version of the `getQuerystring` function from the linked page.

Comment: So the Bit 'iframesrc' is that where I put the URL that will replace the Current Default iframe SRC when loading the page like "abcd.com/thewall?virool" ??
And shouldn't there be something like <script or something before and after the bit shown above? Sorry I don't know what to put before and after the code you posted above to try it out.

And this Goes on the Page with the Iframe on it Right?

Comment: Right, this all goes in your `<script></script>` block inside your `<head>` tag on the page where you want the iframe's src changed. Be sure to set a value for that query string like abcd.com/thewall?iframesrc=virool or whatever. Good luck.